# Is it possible to create a Google Document directly from a Template's JSON

Tags: google-api, google-docs, google-api-client

Since the `Docs API` allows for retrieval of Google Docs via JSON, is there a way to directly inject that JSON data, with alterations, into a new Google Document?  I have several Google Documents that are used as templates for contract agreements, and the data points for all the information to be entered into the templates is already pre-stored in a database.

My goal would be to store the template's JSON server-side and call that data to generate a current agreement and modified agreement by iterating through the placeholder values, inserting database / user input values at those placeholders, and then creating a new Google Doc from that JSON that can be downloaded.  Skipping the step of creating google-side copies, grabbing their ID's, and calling something like `Batch Update`

My inspiration for this came from Federico Tomassetti's post: [A template system for Google Docs: Google Drive automation and PDF generation with Google Execution API](https://tomassetti.me/how-to-generate-invoices-using-a-google-doc-template-and-generate-a-pdf-programmatically/).

However, Federico creates copies of the template and then fills that copy using App Scripts.  I'm currently searching for a solution that would allow for Agreements to be fully generated before being inserted to reduce overhead and simplify permissions, etc.  Skipping the step of creating copies and then editing.

I'm just surprised there isn't some kind of way to directly upload without having to call a `GET` to the template every time, creating copies, and then editing those copies via `Batch Update`.  Hopefully I'm missing some API call that exists, but so far I haven't found anything.